# C# How to pass Datatable results in one array variable

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, arrays, extjs

Good day!

I am trying to achieve to convert all datatable result in one array variable. I searched multiple times, but still cannot achieve my desired result.

Server side code:

```
List<string> holidays = holiday.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("holiday_date")).ToList();
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "myScript", "applyCss(" + holidays + ")", true);
```

Client side code:

```
        var applyCss = function (param1) {

        var paramlength = param1.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < paramlength; i++)
        {
            var css = "#CalendarPanel1-month-day-" + param1 + " {background-color: pink;}";
            Ext.net.ResourceMgr.registerCssClass("script" + i, css);
        }
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right using List. I used var[] but it returns an error.

Will appreciate suggestions / comments / solutions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't the line in for loop be 
`var css = "#CalendarPanel1-month-day-" + param1[i] + " {background-color: pink;}";` ?
Also, what is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

1. I have created a temp datatable for this.
2. Html file where function gets comma separated value after that you can split and use according to your requirement.

   Image Url:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Tae.png
   Image Url:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiAhT.png